# Is there a difference between "not null" and "not null enable"?

Tags: sql, oracle

When we define a table in Oracle we may define the columns as:

```
"NAME" VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL ENABLE
```

My question is I could not understand the meaning of "ENABLE" in this statement. What would be the difference if we just define as  `"NAME" VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL` ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`ENABLE` is the default state, so leaving it out has the same effect. The opposite would be to specify `DISABLE`, in which case the constraint would not be active.

See the [constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52204) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For example
**(1)**

```sql
CREATE TABLE FOO (PRIORITY_LEVEL NUMBER DEFAULT 42 NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

is the same with

```sql
CREATE TABLE FOO (PRIORITY_LEVEL NUMBER DEFAULT 42 NOT NULL);
```

**(2)**

```sql
CREATE TABLE FOO (PRIORITY_LEVEL NUMBER DEFAULT 42 NOT NULL DISABLE);
```

in general, is the same with

```sql
CREATE TABLE FOO (PRIORITY_LEVEL NUMBER NULL);
```