# Sum column in data type varchar2 oracle 21c

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

My question was about the possibility of collecting the time column, especially since the data type is `varchar2`:

```
CREATE TABLE t_video 
(
    video_id NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    video_duration VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    object_video VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 

    CONSTRAINT T_VIDEO_PK PRIMARY KEY ( VIDEO_ID )
); 

INSERT INTO t_video (video_id, video_duration, object_video)
VALUES (1,'00:12:20',song); 
INSERT INTO t_video (video_id, video_duration, object_video)   
VALUES (2,'02:50:30',film);
```

Then I tried and succeeded in solving the problem as follows:

```
-- code sum hours , minutes, seconds in three column
SELECT
    SUM(to_char(substr(video_duration, - 8, 2))) AS hours,
    SUM(to_char(substr(video_duration, - 5, 2))) / 60 AS minutes,
    SUM(to_char(substr(video_duration, - 2, 2))) / 60 / 60 AS seconds 
FROM 
    t_video;

-- code sum hours , minutes, seconds in one column
SELECT
    id_user,
    SUM(ROUND(h1 + h2 + h3, 2)) AS total_hours   
FROM 
    (SELECT                                  
         id_user,                               
         to_char(substr(video_duration, -8, 2)) AS h1,                                  
         to_char(substr(video_duration, -5, 2)) / 60 AS h2,                                 
         to_char(substr(video_duration, -2, 2)) / 60 / 60 AS h3
     FROM                                
         t_video)
GROUP BY
    ROLLUP(id_user);
```

I converted the time to HH24 only and got the required result, which is as follows:

```
  SELECT id_user,
    CAST(SUM(
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM 
    video_duration) * 60 * 60 + 
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM 
    video_duration) * 60 + 
    EXTRACT(SECOND FROM 
    video_duration)) *
    INTERVAL '24' SECOND AS 
    INTERVAL DAY(1) TO 
    SECOND(0)) AS 
    total_duration
 FROM
 t_video
 GROUP BY ROLLUP(id_user);


 RESULT
 id_user     video_duration
 -------     ------------------
 10          + 241 07: 39:  36
 ------------------------------
 20          + 75 13: 40: 00
 ------------------------------
 NULL        + 316 21: 19: 36
```

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL with idiosyncratic date and time support. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use.  [tag:oracle]?  [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Comment: `.... NOT NULL ENABLE` seems to be Oracle syntax.  (see: [Is there a difference between "not null" and "not null enable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595008/is-there-a-difference-between-not-null-and-not-null-enable) )

Comment: inserting the data, given in this question fails.... (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/F1vs3Z_5)).   Can you correct this question ? @sadek920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to change the type of the columns to [`interval day to second`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020). Then you can use Oracle's built in time interval functions.

```
-- Make a new interval day to second column.
alter table t_video add video_duration_new interval day to second;

-- Translate your string durations into intervals.
-- to_dsinterval requires a day, so we add 0 days. This assumes all your video durations are all HH:MM:SS
update t_video set video_duration_new = to_dsinterval(concat('0 ', video_duration));

-- Drop the old column.
alter table t_video drop column video_duration;

-- Replace it with the interval column.
alter table t_video rename column video_duration_new to video_duration;
```

Now getting the number of hours is trivial using `extract`.

```
select extract(hour from video_duration) from t_video;
```

This can also be indexed for performance, and will check the values are formatted properly.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/0AU45Cco).

Comment: Every 12 hours counts as a day according to the last query. I only want an hour, a minute, a second, can I do that? ،

Comment: @sadek920 Sorry, I'm not sure what you're looking for. Would you edit your question and show your expected results, please?

Answer (score 2):

If you are storing times you can use the `INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)` data type (rather than strings) and then your query can be:

```sql
SELECT video_id,                               
       SUM(
         EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM video_duration) * 60 * 60
       + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM video_duration) * 60
       + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM video_duration)
       ) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS total_duration
FROM   t_video
GROUP BY ROLLUP(video_id);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t_video 
(
  video_id       NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  video_duration INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0), 
  object_video   VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
  CONSTRAINT T_VIDEO_PK PRIMARY KEY ( VIDEO_ID )
);

INSERT INTO t_video (video_id, video_duration, object_video)
VALUES (1, INTERVAL '00:12:20' HOUR TO SECOND,'song');

INSERT INTO t_video (video_id, video_duration, object_video)
VALUES (2, INTERVAL '02:50:30' HOUR TO SECOND,'film');
```

Outputs:

| VIDEO_ID | TOTAL_DURATION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | +000000000 00:12:20.000000000 |
| 2 | +000000000 02:50:30.000000000 |
| *null* | +000000000 03:02:50.000000000 |

If you want to format it differently you can cast from the default `INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(9)` to an interval with smaller precision such as `INTERVAL DAY(1) TO SECOND(0)`:

```
SELECT video_id,                               
       CAST(
         SUM(
           EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM video_duration) * 60 * 60
         + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM video_duration) * 60
         + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM video_duration)
         ) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND
         AS INTERVAL DAY(1) TO SECOND (0)
       ) AS total_duration
FROM   t_video
GROUP BY ROLLUP(video_id);
```

| VIDEO_ID | TOTAL_DURATION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | +0 00:12:20 |
| 2 | +0 02:50:30 |
| *null* | +0 03:02:50 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u800n-pf)

Comment: Well done Luuk 